# jquery .get xml file from url

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

So i have a simple task, get an xml feed from a server that is not ours. easy enough, however im running into allow origin control issues and the &callback= tag isnt solving the issue.

```
$.get("http://www.buytopia.ca/feed",data,jloop(),"xml");

function jloop(){
        var count=0;
        //dummy code
        document.write("please work");
        do{
            document.write(count);
            count++;
        }
        while (count<10);

    };
```

so when i run this, the get call is pending, not retieving. ive tried different feeds, like NASA but adding the &callback= doesnt remove access origin problems. All i need is a working chunk of code to get the feed, *preferably* to that buytopia.ca feed because we have access to it and know its permission info. Then i can begin to parse it. Any help would be great! thanks!

Comment: `&callback=` is for JSONP, not XML.

Comment: so am i stuck making a proxy then?

Comment: Yes, that's probably right.

Comment: lame. seems like such an easy thing to do. but its been hell. if the feed is public, is there no easier way to grab it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an ajax call to a local php file (let's say you call it currency.php), and get it through php as in, for example (the php is from ECB's web site, for developers - the ajax is mine)

```
  $XML=simplexml_load_file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

  //the file is updated daily between 2.15 p.m. and 3.00 p.m. CET 

    foreach($XML->Cube->Cube->Cube as $rate){
        //Output the value of 1EUR for a currency code
        echo '1&euro;='.$rate["rate"].' '.$rate["currency"].'<br/>';

        if ($rate["currency"]=='USD') {
            echo 'EUR-> USD RATE: '.$rate["rate"], '<br/>';
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------
        //Here you can add your code for inserting
        //$rate["rate"] and $rate["currency"] into your database
        //--------------------------------------------------
    }
```

Then the ajax call would be something like:

```
<script>
 $.ajax({
        url: 'currency.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {myCurrency: curr,
               myPriceAmt: amount },  
        success: function(data){
            // do any manipulations here

        }
 });
 </script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is buytopia your domain. You cant make ajax calls accross domains. Its called cross site scripting.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: no it is not my domain. its from another project a college has access to.

Comment: This is a security risk and most browsers will not allow you to make ajax calls across domains. You could create a proxy in your own domain. Call a service in your domain that on server side makes a call to the third party (buytopia) and then returns the XML.

Comment: yes i am aware of this. let me put it to you this way. my computer right now can view an xml feed. it does it over http. so isnt their a way to do that in code and parse it? im running this locally at the moemnt

Comment: What do you mean your computer can read an xml feed? Sure you can make and http request to http://www.buytopia.ca/feed but thats not really the issue. You are trying to inject xml via javascript. The browser does not let you inject content from another domain via javascript because its a security issue. Again you can read the Wikipedia article.

Comment: ok, well would switching to JSON (which seems simple though ive never used it before) be a solution to this? much thanks for your replies as well XD

Comment: No, switching to json will not change anything. Its still an ajax call, the browser does not care what the content type is, rather that you are making a cross domain ajax request.

Comment: well thats depressing. so at this point it seems my only hope is a proxy?